# How to build a Windows Toolbar app in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently use an app that looks like this to monitor resource usage via the Windows Toolbar:

[image]

and I wanted to build my own... using psutil and tkinter, I've been able to get to this point as a PoC:

[image] [image]

The percentage in the tray icon is the CPU usage.

However, after hours of googling, I cannot seem to find how to take the data I'm getting and make it into a Windows Toolbar app such as the first screenshot (not just a tiny tray icon)... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is this possible with `tkinter`?, you could hide the top part of the gui and place the window at the bottom position always, im not sure about transparency though. Keep in mind, tkinter is a simple GUI maker.

Comment: @CoolCloud, I'm open to using something other than tkinter for this exact reason. I'm just not sure what else to use haha